# Keep focus after adding Tag to Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Js Module in which I am Adding Tags to Textarea by clicking them. You can see it in my DEMO

Now the problem is when I add tag , it looses focus from Textarea,

e.g now i clicked on tag, and I started typing , it wont type because my cursor will not present in textarea.

All i want is that when I add tag the cursor OR focus should remain in the textarea, so that i dont have to click in textarea in order to type.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPpZ8/4/)

Simple Click on tag and keep typing, you will get to my problem

**I am proving my Code here too :
JS:**

```
$('.tags').click(function (){
        var caretPos = document.getElementById("template_message").selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = $("#template_message").val();
        var txtToAdd = $(this).attr("id");
$("#template_message").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tags_container">
<div> <strong> Add Tags: </strong><br /></div>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[OfferID]"><span >{Offer ID}</span></a></li>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[Username]"><span >{Username}</span></a></li>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[LoadingDate]"><span >{Loading Date}</span></a></li>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[DeliveryDate]"><span >{Delivery Date}</span></a></li>
</div>

<p>
    <textarea style="width:400px;height:100px" name="template_message" class="Required textfield" cols="40" rows="" id="template_message"></textarea>
</p>
```

**Note:** I donot want focus at the End, i want focus after the tag , which i added,so that i can add multiple tags at the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're going to need a function to set the caret position.

Copied from [this forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1419044.aspx):

```
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just call this with:

```
setCaretPosition("template_message", caretPos + txtToAdd.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the focus into the textarea element,

```
$("#template_message").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) ).focus();
```

Added the same in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HPpZ8/7/

Hope it may helps you !!

Comment: What if I add a tag , the cursor should stay after the tag

Comment: @CodeHunter se my answer.

Comment: I donot want focus at the End, i want focus after the tag , which i added,so that i can add multiple tags at the same place

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#template_message").focus().val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
```

Thats the code you´re after, if you want to get the cursor to focus at the end of the text in the textbox:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPpZ8/12/)

Comment: I donot want focus at the End, i want focus after the tag , which i added,so that i can add multiple tags at the same place

Comment: Done please check my post now